# Using the Shield UI ASP.NET MVC events functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shieldui

I have a Shield UI ASP.NET MVC and  am trying to take use of the events functionality. I have taken som source code from the site and have placed it accordingly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/css/shield-chart.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/js/shield-chart.all.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
    function HideChart() {
        document.getElementById("DataSpot").innerHTML = "";
    }
    function chartEventFunction(e) {
        alert("Chart ID: " + e.target.element.attr("id"));
    }
</script>
```

and in my cshtm file I have this:

```
@(Html.ShieldChart()
    .Events(events => events
                .SeriesClick("chartEventFunction")))


    .Name("chartA")
    .AxisX(axisX => axisX.Title(title => title.Text("Speed of Wind")))
    .AxisY(axisY => axisY.Title(title => title.Text("RainFall Quantities")))
    .PrimaryHeader(header => header.Text("Weather - Wind/Precipitation Values"))
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.AxisMarkers(axisMarkers => axisMarkers
        .Enabled(true)
        .Mode(Shield.Mvc.UI.Chart.TooltipAxisMarkerMode.XY)
        .Width(1)
        .ZIndex(3)))
    .ChartLegend(chartLegend => chartLegend
        .Align(Shield.Mvc.UI.Chart.Align.Right)
        .VerticalAlign(Shield.Mvc.UI.Chart.VerticalAlign.Top)
        .RenderDirection(Shield.Mvc.UI.Chart.Direction.Vertical))
    .DataSeries(dataSeries => dataSeries.Scatter()
        .CollectionAlias("January 2008")
        .Data(new object[]{
            new object[]{16.4, 5.4}, new object[]{21.7, 2}, new object[]{25.4, 3}, new object[]{19, 2}, new object[]{10.9, 1}, new object[]{13.6, 3.2}, new object[]{10.9, 7.4}, new object[]{10.9, 0}, new object[]{10.9, 8.2}, new object[]{16.4, 0}, new object[]{16.4, 1.8}, new object[]{13.6, 0.3}, new object[]{13.6, 0}, new object[]{29.9, 0}, new object[]{27.1, 2.3}, new object[]{16.4, 0}, new object[]{13.6, 3.7}, new object[]{10.9, 5.2}, new object[]{16.4, 6.5}, new object[]{10.9, 0}, new object[]{24.5, 7.1}, new object[]{10.9, 0}, new object[]{8.1, 4.7}, new object[]{19, 0}, new object[]{21.7, 1.8}, new object[]{27.1, 0}, new object[]{24.5, 0}, new object[]{27.1, 0}, new object[]{29.9, 1.5}, new object[]{27.1, 0.8}, new object[]{22.1, 2}
        }))
    .DataSeries(dataSeries => dataSeries.Scatter()
        .CollectionAlias("January 2009")
        .Data(new object[]{
            new object[]{6.4, 13.4}, new object[]{1.7, 11}, new object[]{5.4, 8}, new object[]{9, 17}, new object[]{1.9, 4}, new object[]{3.6, 12.2}, new object[]{1.9, 14.4}, new object[]{1.9, 9}, new object[]{1.9, 13.2}, new object[]{1.4, 7}, new object[]{6.4, 8.8}, new object[]{3.6, 4.3}, new object[]{1.6, 10}, new object[]{9.9, 2}, new object[]{7.1, 15}, new object[]{1.4, 0}, new object[]{3.6, 13.7}, new object[]{1.9, 15.2}, new object[]{6.4, 16.5}, new object[]{0.9, 10}, new object[]{4.5, 17.1}, new object[]{10.9, 10}, new object[]{0.1, 14.7}, new object[]{9, 10}, new object[]{2.7, 11.8}, new object[]{2.1, 10}, new object[]{2.5, 10}, new object[]{27.1, 10}, new object[]{2.9, 11.5}, new object[]{7.1, 10.8}, new object[]{2.1, 12}
        }))
    .DataSeries(dataSeries => dataSeries.Scatter()
        .CollectionAlias("January 2010")
        .AddToLegend(false)
        .Data(new object[]{
            new object[]{21.7, 3}, new object[]{13.6, 3.5}, new object[]{13.6, 3}, new object[]{29.9, 3}, new object[]{21.7, 20}, new object[]{19, 2}, new object[]{10.9, 3}, new object[]{28, 4}, new object[]{27.1, 0.3}, new object[]{16.4, 4}, new object[]{13.6, 0}, new object[]{19, 5}, new object[]{16.4, 3}, new object[]{24.5, 3}, new object[]{32.6, 3}, new object[]{27.1, 4}, new object[]{13.6, 6}, new object[]{13.6, 8}, new object[]{13.6, 5}, new object[]{10.9, 4}, new object[]{16.4, 0}, new object[]{32.6, 10.3}, new object[]{21.7, 20.8}, new object[]{24.5, 0.8}, new object[]{16.4, 0}, new object[]{21.7, 6.9}, new object[]{13.6, 7.7}, new object[]{16.4, 0}, new object[]{8.1, 0}, new object[]{16.4, 0}, new object[]{16.4, 0}
        }))
)
```

There is some problem which I thought was caused by the presence of the function declaration, which I put in the right place. What else could be wrong?
And one more thing. For the MVC chart there is not a list of available events I can get (or at least find) on the site. How could I know the full list of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was merely syntax:

```
@(Html.ShieldChart()
.Events(events => events
            .SeriesClick("chartEventFunction")))
```

has one excessive ).

It causes the code after to be left out and probably you were getting a strange output in your browser.

As for the available events- you can see them by invoking the context menu in your IDE.
However here is one list with them written down:

```
Click
Load
PointDeselect
PointSelect
SeriesClick
SeriesMouseOut
SeriesMouseOver
SeriesMouseVisibilityChane
Zoom
```